# App crashing when calling DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm starting to get the following NullPointerException showing up in the Developers Console for one of my Apps

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.lead.soft.deve.myapp.ae.onDateSet(Unknown Source) at
android.app.DatePickerDialog.tryNotifyDateSet(DatePickerDialog.java:148) at 
android.app.DatePickerDialog.onStop(DatePickerDialog.java:155) at 
android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:335) at 
android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:311) at 
com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:178) at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796) at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm using this code to Add and edit a date "DOB" stored in the App MySQL Database, Please note I removed the code that does not apply to the error I'm getting

```
package com.leaders.software.development.myleadersbook;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class tab2 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button ConfirmButton, CallSpouseButton, EmailSpouseButton, HomePhoneButton,
        WorkPhoneButton, CellPhoneButton, EmailAddressButton, SMSButton;

private static final int HELP_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private Long mRowId;
private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private TextView mdobText;
private TextView mdobDisplay;
private Button mPickdob;
private Calendar dobDate;


static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

private TextView activeDateDisplay;
private Calendar activeDate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab2);


    mdobText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dob);

    /* capture our View elements for the start date function */
    mdobDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dob);
    mPickdob = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickdob);
    /* get the current date */
    dobDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    /* add a click listener to the button */
    mPickdob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDateDialog(mdobDisplay, dobDate);
        }
    });

    mRowId = null;
    mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null
            : (Long) savedInstanceState
                    .getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                : null;
    }

    populateFields();

private void updateDisplay(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
    dateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).append("-")
            .append(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("-")
            .append(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));
}

public void showDateDialog(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
    activeDateDisplay = dateDisplay;
    activeDate = date;
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}

private OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {
    // @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        activeDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        activeDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        activeDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateDisplay(activeDateDisplay, activeDate);
        unregisterDateDisplay();
    }
};

private void unregisterDateDisplay() {
    activeDateDisplay = null;
    activeDate = null;
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener,
                activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(
                activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        break;
    }
}

private void populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        mdobText.setText(note.getString(note
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DOB)));

    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    populateFields();

}

private void saveState() {

    String dob = mdobText.getText().toString();

    if (mRowId == null) {
        long id = mDbHelper.createNote(dob);
        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, dob);
    }
}
}
```

As a shot in the dark I added the following to the Manifest file. But still no luck

```
 android:configChanges="orientation"
```

I don't get this error anymore on my test phone running Version 2.3 after I added the above code to my Manifest file but a few others still do

Could it be the space found here between the ""

```
.append(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));
```

**I also found this searching around**

**Add this code in the Activity:**

```
@Override

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

**and using this in the manifest file:**

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

**Is this a good fix or not**

Comment: If you rotate your phone, activeDate and activeDateDisplay  will be null since you only set it once you show the dialog. The dialog gets restored on rotate, tries to call your onDateSet method in which activeDate and activeDateDisplay are now null. Crash.

Comment: I got that part, I have been reading over other peoples post with the same issue.......My question is how to prevent this from crashing out

Comment: Save the necessary parameters in onSaveInstanceState and then reinitialize them in onCreate.

Comment: Catherine......Thanks, put an example would be great